# Substring cut on a Unicode character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

In SQL Server, how can I get a substring to the left of a Unicode character?

For a regular character, I can do this:

```
LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('~', MyColumn) -1)
```

but for a Unicode character, this doesn't work:

```
LEFT(MyColumn, CHARINDEX(N'≈', MyColumn) -1)
```

My current solution is to replace the Unicode character with a non-Unicode character using REPLACE() and then split on that character, but is there a better (less hacky) way?

Comment: What collation are you using and what specific character? You don't generally have to worry about this. `SELECT LEFT(N'123≈456', CHARINDEX(N'≈', N'123≈456') -1)` works fine. Are you using surrogate pairs?

Comment: @MartinSmith  The collation I'm using is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, I just explicitly collated the column to Latin1_General_BIN and it worked!

Comment: So I presume something like `SELECT CHARINDEX(N'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, N'123456'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS), CHARINDEX(N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'123456'  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)`